# Splitting Logs in Different ElasticSearch Document using Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Hi StackOverflow community

I am working on implementing ELK for one of my project. I have a continuous stream of logs getting generated in the format. By continuous stream I mean that logs are getting generated in the following format(Date in starting of each log)

**03 Apr 2017 05:54:30,416 [INFO] Log text**

I want to parse these logs and convert to a structured document using Logstash and then put in ElasticSearch. Logs are going to ElasticSearch but they are in a block(i.e. for one request, all logs generated are part of one elasticsearch document) and every log is not creating a new document.

My logstash's input configuration is like following:

```
    input {
    file {
        path => "/Users/abc/logfile.txt"
        start_position => "beginning"
        codec => multiline {
             pattern => "^([0-9]{2} [A-Za-z]{3} [0-9]{4} [0-9:]{8},[0-9]+)"
             negate => true
             what => previous
         }
    }
}
```

Is there some issue with this configuration? The regex pattern added in multiline codec is tested using regex tester and it correctly identifies Date in the starting of log.

Comment: The multiline codec is used to join multiple lines together so that they can be processed as a group in a filter.  What does the 2nd line of your input file look like because your statement that you have a continuous stream in a given format says that you'll never have anything that doesn't match that format.

Comment: Hi Alcanzar! By continuous stream I mean logs are getting generated continuously and they start with Date in a format as mentioned in the question. I want to publish logs as separate documents, and since logs may be multiline logs(in case of Exception etc.) but will always start with Date in the mentioned format, I added that as multiline codec pattern